# bringToFront does not work in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to make an animation in `RecyclerView` which requires a child to have a bigger z-index than another child. However, when I used the `bringToFront` method in `ViewGroup` it did not work.

Is there any way to bring a child to front in `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Order of children is controlled by the LayoutManager. Built in LayoutManagers have their own strict child order for performance reasons.

Current implementation of [bringToFront](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#1121) simply moves the child to the end of children list which won't play nice with existing LayoutManagers.

If you are targeting Lollipop, you can use [setElevation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setElevation(float)) method.
To target older platforms, you'll need a custom LayoutManager that does not rely on order of children.

Comment: Thanks, but a custom LayoutManager may raise some complexity, I managed to  do some trick to clone the view I want to animate.

Comment: Some update to this 5 year old answer: RecyclerView now offers an API to override the drawing order using `setChildDrawingOrderCallback()`.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, `bringToFront()` does not help; it just changes the order of children in its parent's children array but it doesn't change the order in which children are rendered.

If you are using API-21 or higher you can just change the `Z` value of the view (`view.setZ(..)`) to bring it to the front.

Below API-21 there is a callback you can use: `RecyclerView.ChildDrawingOrderCallback`. With it you can define the order children should be rendered in. (You can also use this with API-21+ in case you don't like the extra shadow you get by changing the `Z` value.)

Example:

```
final int indexOfFrontChild = rv.indexOfChild(desiredFrontView);
rv.setChildDrawingOrderCallback(new RecyclerView.ChildDrawingOrderCallback() {

    private int nextChildIndexToRender;

    @Override
    public int onGetChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int iteration) {
        if (iteration == childCount - 1) {
            // in the last iteration return the index of the child 
            // we want to bring to front (and reset nextChildIndexToRender)  
            nextChildIndexToRender = 0;  
            return indexOfFrontChild;
        } else {
            if (nextChildIndexToRender == indexOfFrontChild) {
                // skip this index; we will render it during last iteration
                nextChildIndexToRender++;
            }
            return nextChildIndexToRender++;
        }
    }
});
rv.invalidate();
```

Basically, `onGetChildDrawingOrder(...)` will be called `childCount` times and in each `iteration` we can specify which child to render (by returning its index).

Comment: Tried this code. Makes the app crash after using it when trying to scroll the RecyclerView.

Comment: @0101100101, are you sure your indexOfFrontChild is in the range of [0, childCount-1]? Or to ask it differently, are you sure your desiredFrontView is a child of your RecyclerView?

Comment: Both yes. The animation actually works perfectly with that code, only scrolling after it doesn't.

Comment: @AlexNewman, depends on how expensive onGetChildDrawingOrder() is. The above implementation is a very cheap one.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above by @Zsolt Safrany is basing on assumption that callback is always called from iteration 0, which as I tested is not true.

Here i am posting working implementation that does not relay on external counter.

```
//index of item you want to be displayed on top
private int indexOfFrontChild = 2;

  @Override
        public int onGetChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int iteration) {
            int childPos = iteration;
            //index must be in at least smaller than all children's
            if (indexOfFrontChild < childCount) {
                //in the last iteration we return view we want to have on top
                if (iteration == childCount - 1) {
                    childPos = indexOfFrontChild;
                }else if (iteration >= indexOfFrontChild) {
                    childPos = iteration + 1;
                }
            }
            return childPos;
        }
```

In my case items were able to change their height so 1 item could take whole screen. So it is nice to check if indexOfFrontChild item is displayable

```
 if (indexOfFrontChild < childCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Image below show a recyclerview with different type of views, one of this child views may draw overlapsed information over the other childrens, I tried to use **bringToFront** and didnt worked.
- The outlined view is a custom **TextScrollableView** which scroll text in case the text doesnt fit.
- When there is a scrolling text this cell accepts a **touch event** and show
  the text inside a **toast baloon** like second image below.

[image]

- To achiev the behavior below I changed the view elevation while showing the toast baloon (after user touch the scrollable text)
- `view.setElevation(float)`

[image]